# Multiple values for the same, autoincremented id, not many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, auto-increment

I have created table INGREDIENTS_LISTS with columuns: INGREDIENTS_LIST_ID, INGREDIENT_ID. The first column is autoincremented and I would love to keep it that way but there is a problem. I can't add multiple ingredients to one ingredients list what makes it kinda pointless. Currently it looks like this:

```
INGREDIENTS_LIST_ID | INREDIENT_ID
         1          | 3
         2          | 5
         3          | 1
```

Is there any INSERT variant 'trick' while creating table I can use to achive this output:

```
INGREDIENTS_LIST_ID | INREDIENT_ID
         1          | 3
         1          | 5
         2          | 1
```

I can see only to options:

> a) Give up with autoincrement but with every INSERT I would have to check current, biggest INGREDIENTS_LIST_ID
> b) Make another column in INGREDIENTS_LISTS let's say ID but it feels like it's going around the problem but not solving it

Thanks in advance!

PS. The case is about SQL obviously. MYSQL to be more precise.

EDIT.
Maybe I should also noticed that i have also other tables like RECIPES with unique ID and INGREDIENTS_LIST_IS included so it's not a many to many relationship. One RECIPE can have only one INGREDIENTS_LIST and INGREDIENTS_LIST is supposed to have multiple INGREDIENTS

Comment: Erm, Don't increment the first column

Comment: Insert the first item, use the returned autoincrement id of ingredients_list_id and use that for the other ingredients.

Comment: What is an ingredients list?

Comment: I don't understand. Is `INGREDIENTS_LIST_ID` a FK from the `INGREDIENTS_LIST` table, then why would you auto-increment it rather than `INREDIENT_ID` (sic)?

Comment: How do you want the DBMS to know, which ingredients are for the same list? My favourite question: *if you were a DBMS how would you manage this having just some inserts with some IDs?* When you answer this question you'll have the solution.

Comment: This sounds like a many to many relationship, where an ingridient can belong to multiple ingridient lists and an ingridient list (recipe?) can have multiple ingridients.